# Modifying VB6 control properties from text editor leads to unexpected behavior

Tags: vb6

So I'm writing a script to modify quickly a VB6 application's interface with COM controls. (Created in C# .net). Most of it works fine, but some panels are giving me a lot of trouble.

Basically, I open the .frm file and read it, and when I find some controls I modify their values or insert new things. When I find a panel, I create a different panel around it so it looks better. I'll put, say `Top = 2340` in the file for my new element. If I open the .frm in notepad, I can clearly see that the value of `Top` is at `2340`. Once I open VB6, the panel's top value is at `Top = 8190`. It also modifies the Left value, but nothing else. If I save and exit vb6, then reopen the .frm in notepad, the `Top` value will be saved at `8190`.

Why does VB6 uses different values than the ones in the .frm file? Is it trying to avoid elements stacking on top of each other ? What is happening between reading the file and opening it, that forces a different value of the `Top` property?

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory, but I believe the issue is that the `ScaleMode` property isn't setup right.  By default, unless the container window has the property, it'll be set to Twips.  So what may be valid under certain containers won't be valid in other containers.

The MDIForm container, for example, forces Twips, and may even re-position objects based on alignment.

If this is the form itself, which I don't think it is but worth mentioning, make sure the `StartUpPosition` is properly set to 0 (Manual).